# Apache Ignite, Cache ID conflict

Tags: c#, caching, ignite

I get this errors:

**[19:55:26,107][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D12201, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0Q201]
[19:55:26,170][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D11301, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0P301]
[19:55:26,203][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D12101, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0Q101]
[19:55:26,227][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D12301, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0Q301]
[19:55:26,249][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D13001, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0R001]
[19:55:26,272][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D13201, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0R201]
[19:55:26,295][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D15101, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0T101]
[19:55:26,352][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D14001, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0S001]
[19:55:26,382][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D13101, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0R101]
[19:55:26,408][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D16001, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0U001]
[19:55:26,432][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#76][ClusterCachesInfo] Ignore cache start request. Cache ID conflict (change cache name) [cacheName=IRE9P1D14101, conflictingCacheName=IRE9P1D0S101]**

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Ignite uses cache name hash code as a unique cache identifier for performance reasons.

In this case, we have a hash collision:

```
      System.out.println("IRE9P1D11301".hashCode()); // -885780178
      System.out.println("IRE9P1D0P301".hashCode()); // -885780178
```

And Ignite can't have two caches with the same id, hence the `Cache ID conflict`. The only way to fix this is to change one of the cache names.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.